# ASP.NET core actions doesn't load. Probably bad routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

Developing url-shorter for self education, and failing in implementing basic functionality as - 2 working views.

Tried different overloads of actions `Redir()`, `Redir(string hash)`.
And so many different routing versions

I got that actions in my controller

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
        return View(null);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string url,[FromServices] IComputeHash computeService)
{       ... 
        return View("Index", url_builder);//url_builder is link like "localhost:44397/Home/Redir?hash=D9F57F9E10FB7CB61F178582A9DD6C1A"
}

public IActionResult Redir() // I also tried version with parameter Redir(string hash)
{
        string hash = Request.Query.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "hash").Value;
        DbField field = db.UrlHashes.Find(hash);// db {key=hash, value=link}
        if (field != null)
            { return View("Redir"); }//View is used for testing is action working at all or not
            //{ return Redirect(field.link); }//actually it just need to redirect to a link
        else
            { return RedirectToAction("Error"); }

}

public IActionResult Error()
{ ... }
```

And currently I use that setup of routing and also tried everything that came into my mind

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "redir",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{Redir}/{hash}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/");
            });
```

When Im going to link of `localhost:44397/Home/Redir?hash=D9F57F9E10FB7CB61F178582A9DD6C1A` type I just got browser error, no loaded view, no redirection to error page, not even crashing with some error. Just plain browser - I cannot load this thing.

Comment: Does http://localhost:44397/Home/Redir/D9F57F9E10FB7CB61F178582A9DD6C1A work if you change `template: "{controller=Home}/{Redir}/{hash}");` to `template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Redir}/{hash}");`?

Comment: @mjwills still doesn't working

Comment: Please show us the request URL from Chrome Developer Tools, Network tab. Also show us the response status code and payload.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks, that helped. Found "no-referrer-when-downgrade" message. And link is working when Im manually changing ```http:\\``` to ```https:\\``` any clues how to auto implement it? My first though just manually add ```https`` to link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting browser response as @mjwills suggested, I found `no-referrer-when-downgrade`error - which means, that I'm came from `https` to `http` level without noticing browser.
So I manually added `https://` to my url constructor. If anyone know how to make this little bit less *hardcoded* fell free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your Route config use this it will fix your problem.
Actually your hash param is part of your url but you're expecting in query string so you need to change in your route..

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "redir",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{Redir}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/");
        });
```